# Add a PropertyGroup into csProj C#

Tags: c#, msbuild, vsix

trying to add (nicely) a property group through a visual studio extension (C#)
[image]

I could do it in XML document class, but it seems clumsy... I seen some chatter about a Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project class.  Can I use this to do in a clean manner??  I have to do this all the time adding three configs for DEV/QAT/PROD.
Any suggestions are welcomed..
Rob

Comment: `System.Xml.Linq` - what's the issue with using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add configurations to the solution and/or to the projects of the solution, and to change its properties (such as the OutputPath), there is an API for that.

For an understanding of solution configurations / project configurations read my post:

[The diagram of the convoluted build configuration automation model (EnvDTE/EnvDTE80) (Part 2)](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2008/09/01/the-fiagram-of-convoluted-build-configuration-automation-model-envdte-envdte80/)

Then see my articles:

[HOWTO: Add / delete build solution configurations from a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/)

HOWTO: Add / delete build project configurations from a Visual Studio add-in (same link)

HOWTO: Add / delete build project platforms from a Visual Studio add-in (same link)

and other related articles in that section of that page.

The samples use "add-ins" (EnvDTE API) rather than packages but you can use EnvDTE also from a package:

[HOWTO: Get an EnvDTE.DTE instance from a Visual Studio package.](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages/)

Finally, once you have a project configuration (EnvDTE.Configuration) you can get/sets its properties through its Properties collection.